# A question about open equivalence relations

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition.** An equivalence relation $\sim$ on a topological space $X$ is said to be open if the projection map $\pi\colon X\to X/\sim$ is open.

Let $U$ be an open set in $X$ and consider the set

\begin{split}
\pi^{-1}\big(\pi\big(U\big)\big)=& \big\{p\in X\;\big|\;\pi(p)\in\pi\big(U\big)\big\}\\
=&\big\{p\in X\;\big|\;[p]\in\pi\big(U\big)\big\}\\
=&\big\{p\in X\;\big|\;[p]=[x]\;\text{for same}\; x\in U\big\}\\
=&\big\{p\in X\;|\;p\sim x\;\text{for same}\; x\in U\big\}\\
=&\bigcup_{x\in U} [x].
\end{split}
I must prove that

> The projection map $\pi$ is open if and only if for every
>   open set $U$ in $X$ the set $\pi^{-1}\big(\pi\big(U\big)\big)$ is open.

**Proof.**$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\pi$ be open. Let $U$ be open in $X$, then $\pi\big(U\big)$ is open, since $\pi$ is continuos $\pi^{-1}\big(\pi\big(U\big)\big)$ is open.

> **Question.** I don't know how to proceed with the vice versa. Could anyone suggest something to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $\pi$ is an open map you have to know how the topology on the quotient space is defined. A set $A$ in the quotient is open if $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$. If $V$ is open in $X$ then $\pi (V)$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(\pi (V))$ is open in $X$ so the converse part is obvious.